# cat command from textbook is not working on my Ubuntu Natty

Tags: bash, r

I am trying to reproduce the following command from my textbook on my system,

`cat("2 3 4 5", "11 13 14 15", file="ex.dat", sep="\n")`

but I keep getting this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"2 3 4 5"'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't `bash` syntax, but rather, is the syntax for the [`cat` command](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cat.html) in the [R language](http://www.r-project.org/) (a programming language used for statistical computing):

> Concatenate and Print
>
> Outputs the objects, concatenating the representations. cat performs much less conversion than print.
>   Usage
>
> ```
> cat(... , file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL,  append = FALSE)
> ```

Comment: omg, I am actually learning R only; what happened is that when I saw `cat` I <somef####nhow> thought that perhaps the first line is creating a file using the linux cat command and the second one is showing how to read the input from the file using R's `scan` command. GOD; this is silly.